# react/jquery: redirecting to another URL with built query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I have an input a simple input box within a render statement in my react component that looks like this:

```
render()
    return(
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input id="searchbox" type="text" />
</form>
);
```

Using the `this.handleSubmit` function, I would like to redirect the contents of the `<input>` to another URL endpoint on my site. Specifically I would like to forward it to `www.mysite.com/confidence` with the contents in the form of a query string, like so:

`www.mysite.com/SB=?the%query%string`

What is the best way to redirect to within handleSubmit()? Here is my pseudocode:

```
 handleSubmit(){
    // contents of search box
    var val = $('#searchbox').val();

    //Create querystring
    var queryString = makeQueryString(val)

    //redirect to /confidence endpoint with built querystring
    redirect('/confidence' + queryString)
}
```

Comment: Do your `makeQueryString` and `redirect` functions exist already?

Comment: @azium No, I would like to know how to properly redirect. I can handle building the querystring part I believe.

Comment: What do you mean by 'properly'? Have you tried `location.href = '/newurl'` ?

Comment: I have tried running `location.href = '/confidence';` and 
    `window.location="/confidence";` within my `handleSubmit()` function and it appears to do nothing. The page simply refreshes and the URL adopts a '?' at the end of it. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: try `event.preventDefault()` as well maybe.. `handleSubmit(event) { event.preventDefault(); location.href = '/url' }`

Comment: You sir, are correct. You can go ahead and answer this page formally and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redirecting:** as simple as calling `location.href = newUrlString`

However, form submitting appears to take precedence so you need to prevent default behaviour.

```
handSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  location.href = newUrlString
}
```

**Getting values from forms in React**:

There's no need to use jQuery here just to get form values in a React component.. if we needed that then why use React at all? Use the `ref` callback function to store the node after the page has loaded, and pass the value to your submit handler.

```
<form onSubmit={event => this.handleSubmit(event, this.inputNode.value)}>
  <input ref={node => this.inputNode = node} type="text" />
</form>
```